# How do I change iPhone language to Lithuanian?

Tags: ios, language

I was asked to translate my iOS app to Lithuanian language. I did it, but now I would like to see the result, and...

cannot change language of my iPhone to Lithuanian. Why?

[image]

There is no such lanaguage on my list, and I am confused.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that Lithuanian is not one of the 31 languages supported natively by iOS. However, since iOS 8, iOS apps can be in **any** language, even if Apple hasn't localised it yet.

In iOS 8 and above you can do this as follows:

- Go to Settings
- Tap on General
- Tap on Language & Region
- Near the top, tap on the blue *Other languages...* option
- In the search field just enter 'lit' to filter the list down to Lithuanian
- Select the language

You may also find these links useful with what you're doing:

- [iOS Supported Language Codes (ISO-639)](http://www.ibabbleon.com/iOS-Language-Codes-ISO-639.html)
- [Build Apps for the World](https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/)

Answer (score 0):

Settings > general > language and region.  Use Edit button to move Lithuanian to the top of the Preferred Languages list.  If not there, use the add language button at bottom.

Comment: I know. There is no lithuanian language...

Comment: Sorry, forgot, no iOS Lithuanian .  You have to put this at top of the preferred language list.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but when I look at the [iOS and iPadOS 16
Feature Availability - System Language](https://www.apple.com/ios/feature-availability/#system-language-system-language), Lithuanian is not present, so I guess it’s apparently not available.

The odd thing is that (on both iPad and iPhone), when I go to *Settings > Language & Region > Add Language* (as explained in the other answers) and search for « Lit » (or « Lithuanian »), I see this:

[image]

It seems that even though it’s not said to be available in the Apple Support article, it’s still an option.

Comment: Certain languages are possible for the total user interface, but many many others are available if an app maker provides the translations.  Lithuanian is in the second category. Apple devices have worked this way for very long time.